# Java RMI remote.exception and unmarshall.exception

Tags: java, rmi

I just started to learn RMI and i am sure i do something wrong so got these exceptions. If anyone can help me i would be grateful.
PS: I am using an RMI plug-in in Eclipse.

Here is my "Remote interface":

```
package org.kovachki.simplermi.common;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface MyRemote extends Remote {
    public String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
}
```

My Server:

```
package org.kovachki.simplermi.server;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

import org.kovachki.simplermi.common.MyRemote;

public class MyRemoteServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MyRemote {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1382837931101952593L;

    protected MyRemoteServerImpl() throws RemoteException {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHello() throws RemoteException{

        return "Server says Hey!";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            MyRemote service= new MyRemoteServerImpl();
            Registry registry= LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost");
            registry.bind("myserver", service);
            System.out.println("The server is ready for greetings!");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And my client class:

```
package org.kovachki.simplermi.client;

import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;

import org.kovachki.simplermi.common.MyRemote;

public class MyRemoteClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new MyRemoteClient().go();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void go()
    {
        try
        {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
            MyRemote service= (MyRemote) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/myserver");

            String s=service.sayHello();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Exception when i run the Server class:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kovachki.simplermi.server.MyRemoteServerImpl_Stub
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1531681105.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.kovachki.simplermi.server.MyRemoteServerImpl.main(MyRemoteServerImpl.java:34)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kovachki.simplermi.server.MyRemoteServerImpl_Stub
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1531681105.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kovachki.simplermi.server.MyRemoteServerImpl_Stub
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler$Loader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClassForName(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: The Registry can't find the class named in the exception.